# Is there a way to chain navigation in React Navigation V5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Suppose I have screens A, B, C. Is it possible to write code in screen A to navigate from A to B then immediately to C?

Answer (score 1):

##### use [dispatch](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch) with [Custom action creators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#custom-action-creators)

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

 const goToC = () => {
    navigation.dispatch((state) => {
      //update navigation state as you want.
      const routes = [
        //current state
        ...state.routes, 
        //add 2 new route to state.
        { name: 'b', params: {id : 100} }, //you can also add params 
        {name: 'c' }
      ];

      return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        routes,
        index: routes.length - 1,
      });
    });
  }
```

full code try snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/navigation-dispatch).

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const containerStyle = { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' };

function ScreenA({ navigation }) {


  const goToC = () => {
    navigation.dispatch((state) => {
      const routes = [
        ...state.routes, 
        { name: 'b', params: {id : 100} },
        {name: 'c' }
      ];

      return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        routes,
        index: routes.length - 1,
      });
    });
  }


  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Text>ScreenA</Text>
      <Button 
        onPress={goToC}
        title="Go to C"
      />
    </View>
  );
}


function ScreenB({ navigation, route }) {
  return  (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(route.params)}</Text>
        <Text>ScreenB</Text>
    </View>
  )
}


function ScreenC({ navigation }) {
  return  <View style={containerStyle}><Text>ScreenC</Text></View>
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="a" component={ScreenA} />
        <Stack.Screen name="b" component={ScreenB} />
        <Stack.Screen name="c" component={ScreenC} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

###### the result

[image]