# How to keep the "Back" functionality in react navigation when navigating from one tab to another that has a drawer and another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an app that has the following navigation structure.

```
<TabNavigator>
  <Screen name="HomeTab" component={HomeStackNavigator} /> 
  <Screen name="ProgramTab" component={ProgramStackNavigator} /> 
</TabNavigator>

<HomeStackNavigator>
  <Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} /> 
</HomeStackNavigator>

<ProgramStackNavigator>
  <Screen name="Programs" component={ProgramsScreen} /> 
  <Screen name="Edit" component={ProgramEditScreen} /> 
</ProgramStackNavigator>

<ProgramsScreen>
  <DrawerNavigator>
    {programs.map=>((p)=>(
      <Screen name={p.id} component={ProgramPreviewScreen}> 
    ))}
  </DrawerNavigator>
</ProgramsScreen>
```

What I want to do is from the home screen go to the program edit screen, but make sure the drawer selection is in the stack.

I got as far as selecting the program drawer, but not to the edit.

```
navigation.navigate('ProgramTab', {
  screen: 'Programs',
  params: {
    screen: item.programId,
    params: {
      programId: item.programId,
      screen: 'Edit',
      params: {
        programId: item.programId,
      },
    },
 },
});
```

If I do the following the "< Back" does not appear unless I go to the Programs tab first, go back home and then select.

```
navigation.navigate('ProgramTab', {
  screen: 'Edit',
  params: {
    programId: item.programId,
  },
 },
});
```

I am thinking it is something with `push` but it gave errors as well (It could be I am using it incorrectly).  I tried the [dispatch approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68515461/is-there-a-way-to-chain-navigation-in-react-navigation-v5) as well and it errors out as well.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few different scenarios I came up with this in the end.

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset(
    {
      routes: [
      {
        name: 'ProgramTab',
        state: {
          routes: [
            {
              name: 'Programs',
              params: {
                screen: item.programId,
                params: {
                  programId: item.programId
                }
              }
            },
            { 
              name: 'Edit', 
              params: { 
                programId: item.programId
              }
            }  
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
);
```

Its weird that I had to combine two different setting techniques (the one with the embedded screen and manipulate the actual `state` of one of the routes.